# rolling 12 month drop down list

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

i am wondering if anyone can help.

i would like to populate a drop down list showing the last 12 months

so the items in the list would be

apr 14

may 14

jun 14

jul 14

aug 14

sep 14

...

apr 15

but next month the list would change to
may 14

jun 14

jul 14

...

may 15

does anyone know how to do this?

many thanks

Comment: and the code you've tried?

Comment: You have 13 months in your lists, not 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Dim MyddlMonthList As ComboBox
Public Sub AddMonthsToDropDown()
    Dim month As DateTime = DateTime.Today
    For i As Integer = 11 To 0 Step -1
        Dim NextMont As DateTime = month.AddMonths(-i)
        MyddlMonthList.Items.Add(NextMont.ToString("MMMM") + " " + NextMont.ToString("yy"))
    Next
End Sub
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: thanks, using your code i managed to rejig it so that it does produce the 13 months that i needed.

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1)
For index As Int32 = 0 To 12
    ddl.Items.Add("{0} {1}", now.ToString("MMM"), now.ToString("yy"))

    now = now.AddMonths(1)
Next
```

Comment: There's a bit of an error here. Your for loop will give 13 months

Comment: @EricRobinson: You are correct, but the OP had 13 months in the examples that were given (even though the title mentioned 12 months).

Comment: unfortuantely this didnt work as it said the Add doesnt accept that many number of arguements :-(